# "start job is running for target ubuntu" stuck at boot

Tags: boot

Stuck at boot for several minutes in following screen
[image]

```
$ sudo systemctl status -l apparmor.service
● apparmor.service - LSB: AppArmor initialization
Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apparmor)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since jeu 2016-03-24 13:31:48 CET; 1h 22min ago
    Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)

mar 24 13:31:48 pgLptp apparmor[470]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
mar 24 13:31:48 pgLptp apparmor[470]: AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.dhcpd in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.dhcpd at line 69: Could not open 'dhcpd.d'
mar 24 13:31:48 pgLptp apparmor[470]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.bin.firefox
mar 24 13:31:48 pgLptp apparmor[470]: AppArmor parser error for /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.dhcpd in /etc/apparmor.d/usr.sbin.dhcpd at line 69: Could not open 'dhcpd.d'
mar 24 13:31:48 pgLptp apparmor[470]: Skipping profile in /etc/apparmor.d/disable: usr.sbin.rsyslogd
mar 24 13:31:48 pgLptp apparmor[470]: ...fail!
mar 24 13:31:48 pgLptp systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=123
mar 24 13:31:48 pgLptp systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: AppArmor initialization.
mar 24 13:31:48 pgLptp systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Unit entered failed state.
mar 24 13:31:48 pgLptp systemd[1]: apparmor.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```